# Tag merge request: [vms] and [openvms]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Can we merge the SO tags [vms](/questions/tagged/vms) and [openvms](/questions/tagged/openvms)?  They refer to the same thing, but both have such low activity that it'll be hard to merge them through the normal tag synonym process.  [vms](/questions/tagged/vms) has more questions and a tag wiki page.